# Can I play old WII console games from Australia and Europe in USA if I buy a US console?

Tags: nintendo-wii

Due to my work I lived in Australia and later in Europe between 2006 - 2008. In Australia I purchased a Wii console and some games for it. Due to the voltage and TV (PAL) standards being the same in Europe, I was later able to use the console and games also in Europe, with some European games as well.

After moving back to USA I started using Xbox but I still have that old console and the games.

The question I wanted to ask is, if I get a new American console, will I be able to play those games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to play the games on a US console if you change the region to e.g. Australia. [This page here](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Regions) says about the Australian region:
"Games from this area will work in European systems and vice versa".

The instructions for changing the region are [here for Wii](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2736/p/604), and [here for Wii U](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1108/p/431).

I have never done this myself however so I would not know if it really solves your issue. Also there could be a limit to e.g. how often the region could be changed. You could contact Nintendo or a place like GameStop that might be able to tell you.

Comment: I thought that you can't set the region to Australia or any European or Asian region in American consoles, and vice versa?

Answer (score -2):

I know you can play Aus games on Euro and vise versa but I don't think you can play games from Aus/Euro to US. Not happening. Tried it once, DIDN'T WORK! Boom boom. Sick sad world.

Comment: Hi Daniel,"tried it once, didn't work" is not much of an argument.